# Consider $Y = X_1 + \ldots + X_n$ and $X_i$ are IID $\sim N(0, 1)$. Is $P(Y \leq y) = P(X_1 \leq y / \sqrt{n})$?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

I think this result comes from the spherical symmetry of the mulvariate gaussian distribution of IID standard normals, but how do you prove this? Does this follow from induction?

Comment: As noted in a now-deleted answer, you can show that $Y \sim N(0, n)$.

Comment: @angryavian Yes, but how does this help me show that $P(Y \leq y) = P(X_1 \leq y / \sqrt{n})$?

Comment: $Y/\sqrt{n} \sim N(0, 1)$ and $P(Y \le y) = P(Y/\sqrt{n} \le y/\sqrt{n})$.

Comment: @angryavian Ah I see. $X_1$ and $Y / \sqrt{n}$ have the same distribution.Can you also think about this problem in terms of spherical symmetry and induction?

Comment: $Y/\sqrt{n} = (X_1 + \cdots + X_n)/\sqrt{n}$ is the projection of the random vector $(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$ onto the direction $(1, ..., 1)$. By spherical symmetry, this has the same distribution as the projection onto $(1, 0, \ldots, 0)$, which is just $X_1$.